# Access database path changing

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have project with database file data.mdb in same folder as project i have given a complete path like:

```
Source=D:\project\project\bin\debug\Data\data.mdb
```

But now I want **to change path to local** because when I change the location of project it not works please help me..

Comment: Where is located this path? If it is in your configuration file then is not a problem to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've hardcoded your connectionstring in your application similar to this:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\project\project\bin\debug\Data\data.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```

In this case your're very unflexible when it comes to changes, as you already noticed.

To be able to change configuration details like a database connectionstring after compilation you should always put that information into a config file (`app.config` or `web.config`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="yourConnection" 
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\project\project\bin\debug\Data\data.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

From within your code you can now read that connection string and use it flexibly:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConnection"].ConnectionString;
var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```

Note: in order to use the `ConfigurationManager`-class you'll first have to add a reference to the `System.Configuration`-assembly in your project. You're then able to use it after putting a using-directive to your class like this: `using System.Configuration;`

And if you don't know it yet: Maybe take a look at [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) which is always a nice reference when you're looking for the right connectionstring.